# Delphi 2010 OXMLDOM

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm migrating my Delphi 7 app to Delphi 2010. We used the Open XML (from http://www.philo.de/).

In Delphi 2010 it seems to be already built in. In the documentation it says so (ms-help://embarcadero.rs2010/rad/Using_the_Document_Object_Model.html)

"and the unit for the Open XML implementation is OXMLDOM"

But I can not find any OXMLDOM in my installation.

Am I missing something? Or the OpenXML support was dropped?

Daniel

Comment: It seems that ADOM (Alternative DOM) is actually the same and new version of OpenXML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that changed. The vendors I see support for are MSXML, Xerces, and ADOM v4.

You can still use Open XML; just create the XML document yourself instead of dragging TXMLDocument on to a form. I use [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com) for most of the stuff I do, and it works fine in D2007, D2009, and D2010.

Comment: @gabr: Thanks. I should have provided the link myself; I got distracted and didn't.